# Can LLVM-based languages be used in OS development?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, osdev

As far as I have understood, LLVM doesn't let you enforce using a specific processor register. Does that mean a language that uses LLVM under the hood, can't be used for developing an OS, a bootloader or such things that for example requires direct access to registers?

Are there any other reasons why LLVM IR *can* or *cannot* be used in OS development?

Comment: For the parts where you need to access specific special registers you would be using assembly anyway.

Comment: @FUZxxl That's exactly what i'm asking for. So I can't get that low-level with LLVM to stop using Assembly?

Comment: If that's what you are asking, yes, you can't. Though, this kind of code is typically very little of an operating system's code. You can't get rid of it by any other mean either.

Comment: @FUZxxl Great, if you don't mind posting it as an answer, I can at least upvote and probably choose as an accepted answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LLVM is an abstract machine. As such, it does not directly allow you to access certain hardware registers. However, you can still use inline assembly (through the `call asm` LLVM bitcode mnemonic) or program the few functions that need access to fixed hardware registers in assembly and call them from your LLVM code.